# What Amazon service should I use in order to serve merged files from an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need an HTTP web-service serving files (1-10GiB) being result of merging some smaller files in S3 bucket. Such a logic is pretty easy to implement, but I need a very high scalability, so would prefer to put it on cloud. What Amazon service will be most feasible for this particular case? Should I use AWS Lambda for that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't achieve that with lambda, since it only offer 512mb for strage, and you can't mount volumes.You will need EBS or EFS to download and process the data. Since you need scalability, I would sugest Fargate + EFS. Plain EC2 instances would do just fine, but you might lose some money because it can be tricky to provision the correct amount for your needs, and most of the time it is overprovisioned.

If you don't need to process the file in real time, you can use a single instance and use SQS to queue the jobs and save some money. In that scenario you could use lambda to trigger the jobs, and even start/kill the instance when it is not in use.

Comment: I don't need to download file, I would like to concatenate file on the fly.

Comment: You will need to download the file from the bucket to proccess, and then upload it again.

Comment: Why? I just need to concatenate several files, so I can download files during request and return a merged file.

Comment: s3 is for storage only, you can't process files in it. That is what EBS and EFS are for.

Comment: I want to write a web service which will just restream multiple S3 files as a single one. I think you still don't get me.

Comment: Yes, I get you just fine. And if the files can get to the size you said, you will definitely need EBS or EFS

Answer (score 0):

**Merging files**

It is possible to concatenate Amazon S3 files by using the [UploadPartCopy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPartCopy.html):

> Uploads a part by copying data from an existing object as data source.

However, the **minimum allowable part size** for a multipart upload is 5 MB.

Thus, if each of your parts is at least 5 MB, then this would be a way to concatenate files without downloading and re-uploading.

**Streaming files**

Alternatively, rather than creating new objects in Amazon S3, your endpoint could simply read each file in turn and stream the contents back to the requester. This could be done via **API Gateway and AWS Lambda**. Your AWS Lambda code would read each object from S3 and keep returning the contents until the last object has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me clarify your goal: you want to have an endpoint, say `https://my.example.com/retrieve` that reads some set of files from S3 and combines them (say, as a ZIP)?

If yes, does whatever language/framework that you're using support chunked encoding for responses?

If yes, then it's certainly possible to do this without storing anything on disk: you read from one stream (the file coming from S3) and write to another (the response). I'm guessing you knew that already based on your comments to other answers.

However, based on your requirement of 1-10 GB of output, Lambda won't work because it has a [limit of 6 MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) for response payloads (and iirc that's after Base64 encoding).

So in the AWS world, that leaves you with an always-running server, either EC2 or ECS/EKS.

Unless you're doing some additional transformation along the way, this isn't going to require a lot of CPU, but if you expect high traffic it will require a lot of network bandwidth. Which to me says that you want to have a relatively large number of smallish compute units. Keep a baseline number of them always running, and scale based on network bandwidth.

Unfortunately, smallish EC2 instances in general have [lower bandwidth](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), although the `a1` family seems to be an exception to this. And Fargate doesn't publish bandwidth specs.

That said, I'd probably run on ECS with Fargate due to its simpler deployment model.

*Beware:* your biggest cost with this architecture will almost certainly be data transfer. And if you use a NAT, not only will you be paying for its data transfer, you'll also limit your bandwidth. I would at least consider running in a public subnet (with assigned public IPs).